# Thumbnails - Error: Our services aren't available right now

Tags: angular, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

Hello Stack Overflow Community.

I'm currently facing a problem and I'd be grateful for any assistance.

I have an image stored at OneDrive and I'm using the following to retrieve a particular image thumbnail:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/{tenant-id}/groups/{group-id}/drive/items/{item-id}/thumbnails/0/small
```

Using Fiddler, the response is 200. Brill! I've got height, url and width. I'm just interested in the url for now.

When I add the url to the `<img>` HTML tag source, nothing loads. On inspection, I find out that the GET returns 503.
I'm working on Angular 4, so at the component typescript I've also tried to add `bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl()` functiom from `DomSanitizer` class. Didn't worked.

I've tried to paste the returned thumbnail's url to the browser at least to see if I can get the visual feedback, but I get:

```
Our services aren't available right now
We're working to restore all services as soon as possible. Please check back soon.

Ref A: 485BC559DAC040639663E5D630A348EA Ref B: AM3EDGE0213 Ref C: 2018-01-30T15:20:58Z
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Please note**: this is actually a second attempt to load an image. As before I've used

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/{tenant-id}/groups/{group-id}/drive/items/{folder-id}/children
```

The response has a webUrl which I've tried to feed into the `img` tag but for some reason it expects me to login to OneDrive manually, then the browser acquires the cookie and images are displayed just fine. But we don't want this, we don't want our users to be forced to login to OneDrive. I'm trying to work out a way to load the images stored in there on my Angular application.
As per permissions, they are all set, I've checked them all.

*Edit 1:
The url returned contains something like:

```
https://ukwest1-mediap.svc.ms/transform/thumbnail?provider=spo&inputFormat=jpg...
```

If I replace https by http into the browser, the image loads up fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you provide a URI to an `IMAGE` tag (`<image src='uri' />`) you are telling the browser to issue a `GET` request to retrieve the image from that URI. This won't work for a file stored in your OneDrive as that `GET` would lack a valid `Authorization` header.

In order to display an image from OneDrive (or a Profile Photo for that matter), you need to retrieve the image content and provide to the image element as a base 64 encoded string.

The content can be retrieved by [adding `/content`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_list_thumbnails#retrieve-thumbnail-binary-content) to the end of your Graph call. This tells Graph to return the content of the image rather than just it's metadata.

Once you have the content, encode it as Base64 and pass it in as a data URI:  `<image src="data:image;base64,{encodedimage}" />`.

Comment: Hi Marc, that's exactly what I was looking for and answers the question. However, if you allow me to be persistent, when I added /content to the end of my Graph call in Fiddler it first gave me a 302 then next gave me a 503. Is this expected? I mean, I was expecting to have a response in accordance with the docs you've shared with me.

Comment: What was the message included with the error? There should be some additional detail that was returned with `302` or `503`. See [Errors](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/errors)

Comment: It is very unreliable. Sometimes it gives `HTTP Error 503.2 - Service Unavailable The serverRuntime@appConcurrentRequestLimit setting is being exceeded.`. Other times it gives `Our services aren't available right now. We're working to restore all services as soon as possible. Please check back soon.`

Comment: Allow me to add this, I've noticed the request gets sent to DataCenter: UK South. Could it be by any chance the servers? I was wondering if I could change the data centre to either Western Europe or Ireland.